# Spring Integration: downloading only new or updated files from FTP server?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration to write FTP-Client for getting files from remote FTP-Server. This service must download files with huge size so it's not optimal to download same file more than one time.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
open fun ftpSessionFactory() = DefaultFtpSessionFactory().apply {
    setHost(env.getProperty(FTP_HOST))
    setPort(env.getProperty(FTP_PORT)!!.toInt())
    setUsername(env.getProperty(FTP_USER))
    setPassword(env.getProperty(FTP_PASSWORD))
}

@Bean
open fun ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() = FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(
    ftpSessionFactory()).apply {
    setDeleteRemoteFiles(false)
    setRemoteDirectory(env.getProperty(FTP_REMOTE_DIRECTORY))
    setFilter(FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter(env.getProperty(FTP_FILTER)))
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel")
open fun ftpMessageSource() = FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
    ftpInboundFileSynchronizer()).apply {
    setLocalDirectory(File(env.getProperty(FTP_LOCAL_DIRECTORY)))
    setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
    setLocalFilter(AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>())
    maxFetchSize = 1
}

@Bean(name = [(PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)])
open fun defaultPoller() = PollerMetadata().apply {
    maxMessagesPerPoll = 1
}
```

Am I downloading all files that matches to FTP_FILTER or just changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alongside with the `FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter` you need to use also `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` for the remote part: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound:

> You can also combine a pattern based filter with other filters, such as an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` to avoid synchronizing files that have previously been fetched, by using a `CompositeFileListFilter`.